# Django POST or GET

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I have a page for teachers to input the marks and registration number of the students..
After input, it gets stored in the database and the students can fill a form which asks for D.O.B and registration number and get's the marks based on that particular registration from the database..

But when I use post request for the students, it shows form is invalid and says that, the registration number already exists..

My views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic.list import ListView
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .models import Mark
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic.edit import FormView
from .forms import ViewResultForm, AddResultForm
from django.contrib import messages



class ViewResultFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'main/home.html'
    form_class = ViewResultForm
    success_url= 'result'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        global registration_number
        global dob
        registration_number = form.cleaned_data['registration_number']
        dob = form.cleaned_data['dob']
        return super(ViewResultFormView, self).form_valid(form)


class MarkListView(ListView):
    model = Mark
    template_name = "main/result.html"
    context_object_name = 'result'
    
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['result'] = context['result'].get(registration_number=registration_number, dob=dob)
        return context

class MarkCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
    model = Mark
    template_name = "main/add.html"
    form_class = AddResultForm

    def form_valid(self, form):

        total_10th = ((form.cleaned_data['class_10_sub_1'] + form.cleaned_data['class_10_sub_2'] + form.cleaned_data['class_10_sub_3'])/300)*30

        total_11th = ((form.cleaned_data['class_11_English'] + form.cleaned_data['class_11_Maths'] +form.cleaned_data['class_11_Physics'] +form.cleaned_data['class_11_Chemistry'] +form.cleaned_data['class_11_Comp_Bio'])/500) * 30

        total_12th = ((form.cleaned_data['class_12_English'] + form.cleaned_data['class_12_Physics'] +form.cleaned_data['class_12_Chemistry'] +form.cleaned_data['class_12_Maths']+ form.cleaned_data['class_12_Comp_Bio'] +  form.cleaned_data['class_12_practicals_Physics'] + form.cleaned_data['class_12_practicals_Chemistry'] + form.cleaned_data['class_12_practicals_Comp_Bio'] )/500)*40
        
        result = total_10th + total_11th + total_12th
        total = form.save(commit=False)
        total.teacher_name = self.request.user
        total.result = result
        total.save()
        message = messages.success(self.request, f'Result added successfully')
        return super().form_valid(form)



class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    template_name = 'main/login.html'
    fields = '__all__'
    redirect_authenticated_user = True


    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('add')
```

home.html:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}
{%load crispy_forms_tags %} 

{% block content %}

<div  class="container mt-5 card shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded">

        <legend>Enter your credentials</legend>

        <form  method="POST">
        
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form | crispy }}


        <input class='btn btn-outline-info' type="submit" value="Submit">
        
        </form>
</div>  

{% endblock content %}
```

result.html:

```
{% extends 'main/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

<div class="container">
{{ result.student_name }}
<br>
{{ result.dob }}
<br>
{{ result.result }} %

</div>

{% endblock content %}
```

So once the teacher enters the marks of the student, I calculate the results and store it in the database.. But bcz the teacher has registered a particular registration number, it shows form is invalid when a student tries to enter the same registration number in the form.. I want the registration number to be unique..

So if I have to use GET in `home.html`, how to access the values of the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should rewrite your `ViewResultFormView.form_valid`, because you do not want `form.save()` to be called in the `super` call. You should retrieve `registration_number` and `dob` from the form and then fill a context for the template with a results of the corresponding student.

Also I do not understand what are those `global` hacks for? If you need to store that info for a several site pages, then you should implement your own authentication for students which will store their auth tokens/cookies somewhere, and then use that authentication info to allow/deny access to certain pages.

Comment: I used `global` because I had to pass it to another page.. I did not know how to do it.. So I used `global`. Could you please link some docs, which shows the better way to do it?
Also, could you please explain how to retrieve data on `GET` request?

Comment: Using `global` in this case is invalid, because an another person can open that specific page and see the results that do not belong to him, because of the cached values in `global` variables.

Comment: Basicly, you want a custom [auth backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/auth/customizing/), [here](https://www.agiliq.com/blog/2019/11/django-custom-authentication-backend/) is a simplified example. By default django attaches authenticated `user` to a request. You either need to link your model to a django `User`, and create `User` for each dob and a registration number, or you need to make your own alternative authentication that attaches your model to a request and stores related session cookies in a browser like django's default auth does (this is a bit harder).

Comment: You can create a custom model, for example `StudentProfile`, link it with `User` as 1-to-1 field. Then after a custom auth you may have a `User` with `StudentProfile` linked, you can try to check it `hasattr(request.user, "student_profile")` and then display/reject certain views.

Comment: For retrieving data on `GET` requests check [class based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/class-based-views/)